# Need to update a set of records in DB using a array using java

Tags: java

I need to update set of records in table  B by fetching the details from another table A .How do I use `for` loop to achieve this using java?

Note- I am fetching the SQL queries from Config properties

```js
   

     //---------- ------------------Get all the required Online data -------
 ArrayList<String> OnlineData_0 = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> OnlineData_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> OnlineData_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> OnlineData_3 = new ArrayList<String>();
       
   String GetOnlineDataQuery =  prop.getProperty("GetOnlineDataQuery_Auth");
       
          OnlineRecords = DataBaseConnector.executeSQLQuery_List2("QA", GetOnlineDataQuery);

then i need to get the column details of reach record 

     //----------------------------Get each online record column details--------
String GetRecordDetail_0 = prop.getProperty("GetRecordDetail") + onlineRecords.get(0);
     String GetRecordDetail_1 = prop.getProperty("GetRecordDetail") + OnlineRecords.get(1);
     String GetRecordDetail_2 = prop.getProperty("GetRecordDetail") + OnlineRecords.get(2);
     String GetRecordDetail_3 = prop.getProperty("GetRecordDetail") + OnlineRecords.get(3);
     String GetRecordDetail_4 = prop.getProperty("GetRecordDetail") + OnlineRecords.get(4);



Now i need to uddate the above column details to records in different table

 

     
       //-----------------update the column details in Table B---------------------------------------------
String Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth_0 = prop.getProperty("Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth") +  OnlineRecords.get(0);
      String Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth_1 = prop.getProperty("Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth") +  OnlineRecords.get(1);
      String Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth_2 = prop.getProperty("Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth") +  OnlineRecords.get(2);
      String Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth_3 = prop.getProperty("Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth") +  OnlineRecords.get(3);
      String Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth_4 = prop.getProperty("Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth") +  OnlineRecords.get(4);
      
      String update_ISO8583_Query_0 = DataBaseConnector.executeSQLQuery("QA", Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth_0);
      String update_ISO8583_Query_1 = DataBaseConnector.executeSQLQuery("QA", Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth_1);
      String update_ISO8583_Query_2 = DataBaseConnector.executeSQLQuery("QA", Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth_2);
      String update_ISO8583_Query_3 = DataBaseConnector.executeSQLQuery("QA", Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth_3);
      String update_ISO8583_Query_4 = DataBaseConnector.executeSQLQuery("QA", Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth_4);
```

how to put the above in an for loop so that i can update records

Comment: Could you describe the problem you have in more detail? The code that is included isn’t very helpful

Comment: [Oracle Java Tutorial: The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: Please correct your code formatting/indenting. Your code is unreadable. http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against doing sql queries in for loops. This would place a great burden on your database and might crash it. You should look into the bulk operations of your database.

```
for(int i=0; i<onlineRecords.size(); i++ ){
        String GetRecordDetail_i = prop.getProperty("GetRecordDetail") + onlineRecords.get(i);
        String Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth_i = prop.getProperty("Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth") +  OnlineRecords.get(i);
        String update_ISO8583_Query_i = DataBaseConnector.executeSQLQuery("QA", Query_UpdateClearingRecord_Auth_i);
```

}